# Dirac probability measure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, calculus, probability-density

I want to implement densities of probability measures in Matlab. For that I define `density` as a function handle such that the integral of some function f (given as a function handle) on the interval [a,b] can be computed by

```
syms x
int(f(x)*density(x),x,a,b)
```

When it comes to the Dirac measure the problem is that

```
int(dirac(x),x,0,b)
```

delivers the value 1/2 instead of 1 for all b>0. However if I type

```
int(dirac(x),x,a,b)
```

where a<0 and b>0 the returned value is 1 as it should be. For this reason multiplying by 2 will not suffice as I want my density to be valid for all intervals [a,b]. I also dont want to distinct cases before integrating so that the code remains valid for a large class of densities.

Does someone know how I can implement the Dirac probability measure (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure)) in Matlab?

Comment: The Dirac distribution has all its weight concentrated at `0`. So I'm not sure how to define the integral when the lower integration limit is precisely `0`. Can't you use for example `-inf` as lower integration limit? Or maybe use a limit: `limit(int(dirac(x),x,a,b),a,0,'left')` does give `1`

Comment: @Luis Mendo In my question I specified the intervall of integration to be closed. Hence the Integral of the dirac would be wel define (it only counts if 0 is contained in the  intervall). The limit solution is nice, but since I want to compute integrals for different densities i dont want to always compute the limit (I probably adopt this solution anyways if nobody come up with a better one).

Comment: Let me retreat slightly and take a different approach. There's no unique, accepted definition for int(delta, 0, b). The problem here isn't that you're getting the "wrong" answer as that you want to impose a different convention somehow on what the delta function is than what was provided by Matlab. (Their choice is defensible but not unique.) If you evaluate this in Wolfram Alpha, for example, it will give you theta(0) - which is not defined as anything in particular. Here theta is the Heaviside function. If you want to impose your own convention here, implement your own delta function.

Comment: @Brick To get help with that (Building my own delta probability density) I posed the question. However, I might have been imprecise, as I mean the definition given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure).

Answer (score 1):

There's no unique, accepted definition for int(delta, 0, b). The problem here isn't that you're getting the "wrong" answer as that you want to impose a different convention somehow on what the delta function is than what was provided by Matlab. (Their choice is defensible but not unique.) If you evaluate this in Wolfram Alpha, for example, it will give you theta(0) - which is not defined as anything in particular. Here theta is the Heaviside function. If you want to impose your own convention, implement your own delta function.

**EDIT**

I see you wrote a comment on the question, while I was writing this answer, so....  Keep in mind that the Dirac measure or Dirac delta function is not a function at all. The problem you're having, along with what's described below, all relate to trying to give a functional form to something that is inherently not a function.  What you are doing is not well-defined in the framework that you have in Matlab.

**END OF EDIT**

To put the point about conventions in context, the delta function can be defined by different properties.  One is that int(delta(x) f(x), a, b) = f(0) when a < 0 < b.  This doesn't tell you anything about the integral that you want.  Another, which probably leads to an answer as you're getting from Matlab, is to define it as a limit.  One (but not the only choice) is the limit of the zero-mean Gaussian as the variance goes to 0.

If you want to use a convention int(delta(x) f(x), a, b) = f(0) when a <= 0 < b, that probably won't get you in much trouble, but just keep in mind that it's a convention you've chosen more than a "right" or 
"wrong" answer relative to what you got from Matlab.

As related note, there is a similar choice to be made on the step function (Heaviside function) at x=0.  There are conventions in which is is (a) undefined, (b) -1, (c) +1, and (d) 1/2.  None is "wrong."  This probably corresponds roughly to the choice on the Dirac function  since the Heaviside is (roughly) the integral of the Dirac.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question (which stands in the last line). The dirac measure in terms of a probability measure is uniquely defined ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure)). I edited my question to make it more precise.

Comment: @Vincent.W. I'l try one more time, then I'm out. The definition that you reference does not provide a definition of a function at all. It is a unique definition of *something* mathematical, but that something is not a function. Your framework in Matlab requires a function. What you want does not exist.

Comment: @Vincent.W. Maybe I can rephrase Brick's comment as follows: What you want is an integral with respect to Dirac measure. Matlab only considers Lebesgue measure. The integral of Dirac's delta with respect to Lebesgue measure doesn't exist unless you consider distributions (instead of just functions). So you'd have to be able to handle either distributions or arbitrary measures, none of which is likely to be possible with an off-the-shelf Matlab function